# rmd with shiny: update reactiveValues several times without creating many copies

Tags: r, shiny

In my rmd file with `runtime: shiny` I have two options to load data

1. upload data and
2. use a predefined data set:

```
fluidRow(
  column(6,
         fileInput(inputId = "upload", label = NULL, buttonLabel = "upload data",
         placeholder = "bla.txt", accept = ".txt", width = "100%")
  ),
  column(6,
         actionButton(inputId = "prepData", label = "load data", width = "100%"))
)
```

If one of the button is clicked the following code runs:

```
FileName <- "bla.txt"
global <- reactiveValues(file = NULL)
# import uploaded data
observeEvent(input$upload, {
  global$file <- "uploaded"
  global$data <- vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ",")
})
# import prepared data
observeEvent(input$prepData, {
  global$file <- "prepared"
  global$data <- vroom::vroom(paste0("data/", FileName), delim = ",")
})
```

So now the data is stored in `global$data` and the source is stored in `global$file`.

Next, I want to show the data using `renderDT(datatable(global$data))`, apply some changes to the data like `global$data <- global$data %>% mutate(foo = 1)` and show it again, apply more changes, show it again, apply more changes, show it again, and so on.

I got this to work making several copies of the data like so:

```
df1 <- reactive({global$data %>% mutate(foo = 1)})
renderDT(datatable(df1()))
df2 <- reactive({df1() %>% mutate(bar = 2)})
renderDT(datatable(df2()))
...
```

So, my question is: How can I prevent making several copies of the data?

I tried to put this in an `observe` block, but using multiple `observe` blocks would trigger all of them whenever `global$data` changes. I also tried to add a `global$step` (counting up by one after every step) with `observeEvent` to run each code chunk only once, but didn't succeed.